operator-sdk is making a csv from a ghost file
I'm trying to generate a bundle for an operator but the operator-sdk is taking a CSV definition from anywhere I do not know and I do not find anything
They way I'm doing is using kustomize build to take the definitions and the pipe into operator-sdk generate bundle to generate the bundle. The theory says that this kustomize created files will be used to create the bundle but the reality is that operator-sdk is not taking them.
For example:
apiVersion: operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterServiceVersion
metadata:
  annotations:
    alm-examples: '[]'
    capabilities: Basic Install
  name: example-operator.v0.0.0
  namespace: placeholder
spec:
  apiservicedefinitions: {}
  customresourcedefinitions: {}
  description: |
    Very Long Description
  displayName: Example Operator
  icon:
  - base64data: "base64_enconded_image"
    mediatype: image/jpeg
  install:
    spec:
      deployments: null
    strategy: ""
  installModes:
  - supported: false
    type: OwnNamespace
  - supported: true
    type: SingleNamespace
  - supported: false
    type: MultiNamespace
  - supported: true
    type: AllNamespaces
  keywords:
  - assessment
  - audit
  - state
  - cluster
  links:
  - name: Example Inc.
    url: https://example.com
  maturity: alpha
  minKubeVersion: 1.16.0
  provider:
    name: Example
    url: example.com
  version: 0.0.0

But it is resulting the following under the bundle folder:
apiVersion: operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterServiceVersion
metadata:
  annotations:
    alm-examples: |-
      [
        {
          "apiVersion": "custom.example.com/v1alpha1",
          "kind": "Memcached",
          "metadata": {
            "labels": {
              "app.kubernetes.io/created-by": "example-operator",
              "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "memcached-sample",
              "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": "kustomize",
              "app.kubernetes.io/name": "memcached",
              "app.kubernetes.io/part-of": "example-operator"
            },
            "name": "example-sample"
          },
          "spec": {
            "author": "",
            "author_email": "",
            "client": "",
            "git_token": ""
          }
        }
      ]
    capabilities: Basic Install
    createdAt: "2024-04-18T08:02:35Z"
    operators.operatorframework.io/builder: operator-sdk-v1.34.1
    operators.operatorframework.io/project_layout: ansible.sdk.operatorframework.io/v1
  name: example-operator.v0.0.44
  namespace: placeholder
spec:
  apiservicedefinitions: {}
  customresourcedefinitions:
    owned:
    - kind: Memcached
      name: memcached.custom.example.com
      version: v1alpha1
  description: Example Operator description. TODO.
  displayName: Example Operator
  icon:
  - base64data: ""
    mediatype: ""
  install:
    spec:
      clusterPermissions:
      - rules:
        - apiGroups:
          - authorization.openshift.io
          resources:
          - '*'
          verbs:
          - '*'
        - apiGroups:
          - rbac.authorization.k8s.io
          resources:
          - '*'
          verbs:
          - '*'
        - apiGroups:
          - ""
          resources:
          - secrets
          - configmaps
          - serviceaccounts
          - pods
          - pods/exec
          - pods/log
          verbs:
          - create
          - delete
          - get
          - list
          - patch
          - update
          - watch
        - apiGroups:
          - apps
          resources:
          - deployments
          - daemonsets
          - replicasets
          - statefulsets
          verbs:
          - create
          - delete
          - get
          - list
          - patch
          - update
          - watch
        - apiGroups:
          - batch
          resources:
          - jobs
          verbs:
          - create
          - delete
          - get
          - list
          - patch
          - update
          - watch
        - apiGroups:
          - custom.crossvale.com
          resources:
          - assessments
          - assessments/status
          - assessments/finalizers
          verbs:
          - create
          - delete
          - get
          - list
          - patch
          - update
          - watch
        - apiGroups:
          - authentication.k8s.io
          resources:
          - tokenreviews
          verbs:
          - create
        - apiGroups:
          - authorization.k8s.io
          resources:
          - subjectaccessreviews
          verbs:
          - create
        serviceAccountName: example-operator-controller-manager
      deployments:
      - label:
          app.kubernetes.io/component: manager
          app.kubernetes.io/created-by: new-operator
          app.kubernetes.io/instance: controller-manager
          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kustomize
          app.kubernetes.io/name: deployment
          app.kubernetes.io/part-of: new-operator
          control-plane: controller-manager
        name: example-operator-controller-manager
        spec:
          replicas: 1
          selector:
            matchLabels:
              control-plane: controller-manager
          strategy: {}
          template:
            metadata:
              annotations:
                kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-container: manager
              labels:
                control-plane: controller-manager
            spec:
              containers:
              - args:
                - --secure-listen-address=0.0.0.0:8443
                - --upstream=http://127.0.0.1:8080/
                - --logtostderr=true
                - --v=0
                image: gcr.io/kubebuilder/kube-rbac-proxy:v0.14.1
                name: kube-rbac-proxy
                ports:
                - containerPort: 8443
                  name: https
                  protocol: TCP
                resources:
                  limits:
                    cpu: 500m
                    memory: 128Mi
                  requests:
                    cpu: 5m
                    memory: 64Mi
                securityContext:
                  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
                  capabilities:
                    drop:
                    - ALL
              - args:
                - --health-probe-bind-address=:6789
                - --metrics-bind-address=127.0.0.1:8080
                - --leader-elect
                - --leader-election-id=new-operator
                env:
                - name: ANSIBLE_GATHERING
                  value: explicit
                image: ghcr.io/crossvale-inc/example-operator:0.0.44
                livenessProbe:
                  httpGet:
                    path: /healthz
                    port: 6789
                  initialDelaySeconds: 15
                  periodSeconds: 20
                name: manager
                readinessProbe:
                  httpGet:
                    path: /readyz
                    port: 6789
                  initialDelaySeconds: 5
                  periodSeconds: 10
                resources:
                  limits:
                    cpu: 500m
                    memory: 768Mi
                  requests:
                    cpu: 10m
                    memory: 256Mi
                securityContext:
                  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
                  capabilities:
                    drop:
                    - ALL
              securityContext:
                runAsNonRoot: true
              serviceAccountName: example-operator-controller-manager
              terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      permissions:
      - rules:
        - apiGroups:
          - ""
          resources:
          - configmaps
          verbs:
          - get
          - list
          - watch
          - create
          - update
          - patch
          - delete
        - apiGroups:
          - coordination.k8s.io
          resources:
          - leases
          verbs:
          - get
          - list
          - watch
          - create
          - update
          - patch
          - delete
        - apiGroups:
          - ""
          resources:
          - events
          verbs:
          - create
          - patch
        serviceAccountName: example-operator-controller-manager
    strategy: deployment
  installModes:
  - supported: false
    type: OwnNamespace
  - supported: false
    type: SingleNamespace
  - supported: false
    type: MultiNamespace
  - supported: true
    type: AllNamespaces
  keywords:
  - example-operator
  links:
  - name: Example Operator
    url: https://example-operator.domain
  maintainers:
  - email: your@email.com
    name: Maintainer Name
  maturity: alpha
  provider:
    name: Provider Name
    url: https://your.domain
  version: 0.0.44

As you see it is taking something that nothing relates with the base manifest I have
Any idea? Cause I'm very frustrated at that point
Thanks in advance.

Why did you tag makefile?

I run it from Makefile generated with operator-sdk init command

OK, if you think your problem comes from make, please edit your question to show your Makefile and the command you use to invoke make. Else, if you think make has nothing to do with your problem, you should probably remove the makefile tag.
